# Как привязать две коллекции к одному ItemsControl?

Tags: c#, wpf

Всем привет! Не могу решить проблему.

Дано:

1. Две коллекции во `ViewModel`.
2. Один `ItemsControl`.

Задача:

1. Привязать обе коллекции к одному `ItemsControl`.
2. Одну коллекцию нужно время от времени фильтровать и сортировать во `ViewModel`.

Что пробовал:

1. `CompositeCollection` - не привязывается ко `ViewModel`.
2. `IMultiValueConverter`+ две `ICollectionView` - фильтр работать не будет при вызове `Refresh()` у одной из них.

Хотелось бы использовать сортировку и фильтрацию именно как у `ICollectionView` и во `ViewModel`, не пересоздавая ее целиком при каждой фильтрации.

Как это можно сделать?

**UPDATE**

Вот так кажется завелось.

Во `ViewModel`:

```
public ICollectionView SomeCollectionView1 => _someCollectionSource1?.View;
public ICollectionView SomeCollectionView2 => _someCollectionSource2?.View;
```

В xaml:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
    <CompositeCollection>
        <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Path=SomeCollectionView1, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"/>
        <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Path=SomeCollectionView2, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"/>
    </CompositeCollection>
</ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
```

Comment: А если передать из VM две коллекции, а в XAML’е связать их через CompositeCollection? Так вы пробовали?

Comment: @Vlad, так и делал, требует статичных ресурсов. Обновил вопрос, заработало кажется.

Comment: А нельзя просто `<CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Path=C1}"/>` и без locator’а?

Comment: @VladD, нет. В таком случае привязка не работает. А во всех примерах предлагается создать статичный ресурс `CollectionViewSource`, к нему привязать коллекцию как `Source`, и потом его передавать как статичный ресурс в `CollectionContainer`. Сам же `CollectionViewSource` не принимает `ICollectionView` и ему подобные.

Comment: Хм, интересно, надо будет на досуге покурить документацию.

Comment: @VladD [`The CompositeCollection has no DataContext, the bindings in the CollectionContainers will not work if they bind directly to a property (which implicitly uses the DataContext as source).`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6446923/312041)

Comment: @tym32167: А, и правда, мы ж не в визуальном дереве!